# Facebook app id doesn't work (Android)

Tags: android, facebook

When using Facebook app id, sharing won't work. GraphObject == null. The request being Request request = new Request(session, "me/feed", postParams, HttpMethod.POST, callback); Looks like something's wrong with the hash key, but after I created another Facebook app and used its id, sharing got allright. I'm using the same Hash key in both apps.

Comment: If you look at the Logcat output, you can see what hash key is expected on the facebook developers app page.

Comment: See this answer:http://stackoverflow.com/a/13488560/1248068 on how to generate the hash key via code. You may also copy this code into your app and keep watching the Logcat View in Eclipse. Add the hash key that you see into your account at developers.facebook.com

Comment: You did not read the question. I added the hash key into your account at developers.facebook.com. I have 2 applications at developers.facebook.com. In one works in the other is not.